# Is it polite to ask for an attachment from the recipient?

Tags: application

I applied for a Summer Programme, but l forgot to save the attachment I have sent. Now I need the attachment. Should I do the work again or ask for it from the recipient?

Comment: Have you checked your "sent messages" folder?

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't really be any problem with this other than a bit of embarrassment. Just explain what happened and ask if it is still possible to have a copy back. Worth a chuckle, but no more. I don't see how it should affect your application provided that the institution is ethical. Humans make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest as have others in the comment, that you look in your "sent messages" folder, it should be there with the attachment.

This may depend on the mail program as well as how the detail is set up ie keep a copy locally etc

But it is the first place I would look.